# Ruby Loops While Statements

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings `dictionary` and a string `target`:

```
dictionary = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'abc']
target = 'abba'
```

My goal is to return combinations of words from `dictionary` that can make up `target`. It should return something like this

```
['a abc', 'a a b c', 'a ab c']
```

This is what I have:

```
def possible_combinations(dictionary, target)
        results = [] #eventually an array of results 
        i = 0 #to go through the dictionary index starting at 0
        t = 0 #to go through the target index starting at 0
        while i < dictionary.count #while 0 is less than the total index in dict
            while t < target.length 
                if dictionary[i] == target[t]#dict is not changing but target[t] is changing
                    puts 'I am ' + dictionary[i] + ' at DICT for now'
                    puts 'I am ' + target[t] + ' at t for now'
                    puts 'I match somewhere in target so I am added.'#dict[1] is not happening here.
                    # results.push(dictionary[i])
                    if results.empty? 
                        results.push(dictionary[i])
                        puts results
                    else
                        results = results[0] + ' ' + dictionary[i] #this is not entirely working?
                        puts results
                    end
                else
                    puts 'forget about me'
                end 
            t = t + 1
            end 
        i = i + 1
        end 
    end
```

and when I run it, I get this:

```
I am a at DICT for now
I am a at t for now
I match somewhere in target so I am added.
a
forget about me
forget about me
I am a at DICT for now
I am a at t for now
I match somewhere in target so I am added.
a a
```

I notice that `target[t]` is changing, but `dictionary[i]` is not. I don't understand nested while loops. I think the inner while loop has to finish before it heads to the outer, so `dictionary[i]` is getting stuck. I want to iterate over `i` for both `dictionary` and `target`, so I am using nested while loops.

If `target = 'aaaba'`, I get this:

```
I am a at DICT for now
I am a at t for now
I match somewhere in target so I am added.
a
I am a at DICT for now
I am a at t for now
I match somewhere in target so I am added.
a a
I am a at DICT for now
I am a at t for now
I match somewhere in target so I am added.
a a
forget about me
I am a at DICT for now
I am a at t for now
I match somewhere in target so I am added.
a a
```

Notice how the results got stuck with two `'a'` but not three or four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `while` you can use `each` on the `dictionary` and `each_char` on the `target`

```
dictionary.each do |word|
  target.each_char do |char|
    puts word, char
  end
end
```

The problem w/ your current loops is that you are initializing `t = 0` outside both loops, so you only loop through the `target` once before the inner `while` condition is always false. If you move that declaration inside the first while loop you will get a result more similar to what you expect

Answer (score 0):

```
ri Array.each
ri String.index
```

You're doing this in the most un-ruby like way possible. Read the chapter on the Enumerable module. Look up all the methods String supports. There is almost always a better way than using while in Ruby.

http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Note that while String.[1] works Strings are not enumerable, you'd be better off to split the string into an Array of chars if you want to enumerate over it. Or better yet use string search functions rather than direct comparisons. In your
code

dictionary[i] is a string

while

target[i] is a single char.

So you test will never be equal when the dictionary elements are longer than one char.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more Ruby-like way to write your program:

```
def possible_combinations(dictionary, target)
  results = #eventually an array of results 
  dictionary.each do |d|
    str = ''
    target.each do |tl
      if d == t #dict is not changing but target[t] is changing
        puts 'I am ' + d + ' at DICT for now'
        puts 'I am at target ' + t + ' now'
        puts 'I match somewhere in target so I am added.' #dict[1] is not happening here.
        str = << ' ' unless str.empty?
        str << d
        puts results
      else
        puts 'forget about me'
      end 
    end
    results << str
  end 
end
```

It took just a couple minutes to do this translation.  I mainly removed the indices, so the iterations are over elements of the `dictionary` and `target` objects.